# A Frame is not shown beacuase the action done previously is time consuming

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I Have a tkinter app with a MVC pattern. I have cretaed a main window with 2 frames, one for page selecter an another to show the different pages.

The function for handle pages is:

```
def cambiar_modeloFinal(self, id):
        self.regresionFinalV.modeloGHI.config(bg=inactiveColor, activebackground=backgroundColor)
        self.regresionFinalV.modeloTEMP.config(bg=inactiveColor, activebackground=backgroundColor)
        self.regresionFinalV.modeloAP.config(bg=inactiveColor, activebackground=backgroundColor)
        self.regresionFinalV.modeloRH.config(bg=inactiveColor, activebackground=backgroundColor)
        
        self.model.set_modeloFinal(self.regresionFinalV.variable, self.regresionFinalV.modeloSelected.get())  
        
        if(id == 1):
            self.regresionFinalV.variable = "GHI"
            print(self.model.get_finalGHI())
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloSelected.set(self.model.get_finalGHI())
            self.regresionFinalV.modelos = self.model.get_modelosGHI()
            self.regresionFinalV.rellenar_tabla()
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloGHI.config(bg= activeColor, activebackground=activeColor)

        elif(id == 2):
            self.regresionFinalV.variable = "TEMP"
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloSelected.set(self.model.get_finalTEMP())
            self.regresionFinalV.modelos = self.model.get_modelosTEMP()
            self.regresionFinalV.rellenar_tabla()
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloTEMP.config(bg= activeColor, activebackground=activeColor)

        elif(id==3):
            self.regresionFinalV.variable = "AP"
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloSelected.set(self.model.get_finalAP())
            self.regresionFinalV.modelos = self.model.get_modelosAP()
            self.regresionFinalV.rellenar_tabla()
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloAP.config(bg= activeColor, activebackground=activeColor)
        else:
            self.regresionFinalV.variable = "RH"
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloSelected.set(self.model.get_finalRH())
            self.regresionFinalV.modelos = self.model.get_modelosRH()
            self.regresionFinalV.rellenar_tabla()
            self.regresionFinalV.modeloRH.config(bg= activeColor, activebackground=activeColor)
```

The button for pages controller is:

```
 self.view.tmyButton.bind("<Button>", lambda event: self.cambiar_pagina(4))
```

When I press this button everuthing goes good and the new Frame is shown. However when pressing another button that should do almost the same:

```
self.regresionFinalV.tmyB.bind("<Button>", lambda event: self.cambiar_tmy(event))
```

with this function

```
def cambiar_tmy(self, event):
        self.model.set_modeloFinal(self.regresionFinalV.variable, self.regresionFinalV.modeloSelected.get())  
        selected_value = self.regresionFinalV.dropboxP.get()
        if(self.model.isPosible_calcularTMY() == False):
            showwarning('Advertencia', 'Es necesario seleccionar un modelo para cada variable disponible.')
        elif selected_value == "":
            showwarning('Advertencia', 'Debe indicar el tipo de TMY que desea calcular.')
        else:
            options = ["P50", "P75", "P90", "P99"]
            index = options.index(selected_value)
            probs = [0, 0.25, 0.1, 0.01]
            selected_prob = probs[index]
            self.model.type_tmy = (selected_value, selected_prob)
            self.model.calcular_tmy()
            self.cambiar_pagina(4)
            self.view.regresionFinalButton.event_generate("<Button>")
            self.view.tmyButton.event_generate("<Button>")

        return 'break'
```

It is like it changes the page but the whole page is blank.

Comment: It is better to run time-consuming task using thread.

Comment: I have tried to use thread but it still happens the same